# Does scipy.linalg.inv check whether the matrix is diagonal?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

Getting the inverse of a diagonal matrix is very simple and does not require complex methods. Does `scipy.linalg.inv` check whether the matrix is diagonal before it applies more complex methods or do I need to check this myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [the Github code of `scipy.linalg.inv`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/linalg/basic.py#L907-L979), function `inv` first calls

```
getrf, getri, getri_lwork = get_lapack_funcs(('getrf', 'getri','getri_lwork'),
```

Then function `getrf` does it job to give the LU decomposition and so on. Now we have to investigate how `getrf` function gives the LU decomposition. Because if it checks if it's diagonal before to process the input matrix, then no need to check it yourself.

Function `getrf` is obtained by calling [`_get_funcs`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/linalg/blas.py) but I can't go further from there (`_get_funcs` is called with the following arguments `_get_funcs(names, arrays, dtype, "LAPACK", _flapack, _clapack, "flapack", "clapack", _lapack_alias)`).

I suggest that you run an experiment with a large diagonal matrix to compare the time given to spit the output with `linalg` and an inversion by hand.

---

**Update** (by question author):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import inv
a = np.diag(np.random.random(19999))
b = a.copy()
np.fill_diagonal(a, 1/a.diagonal())
c = inv(b)
```

does not even require a time measuring tool: It it very obvious that `inv` is much slower... (that is surprisingly disappointing).

Comment: Right. An issue should be opened on the Github project. Maybe other special cases could be considered to boost the inversion.

Answer (score 2):

Please check: [scipy.linalg.inv](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.inv.html)
If you put scipy.linalg.inv in try except if it raises LinAlgError when matrix a is singular. The determinant for singular matrix it zero.

```
try:
    # your code that will (maybe) throw  scipy.linalg.inv(your matrix)

except np.linalg.LinAlgError as err:
    # It shows your matrix is singular
    # Its determinant of a matrix is equal to zero
    # The matrix does not have an inverse.
    # You can conclude if the matrix is diagonal or not
```

> If the determinant of a matrix is equal to zero:
>
> The matrix is less than full rank. The matrix is singular. The matrix
>   does not have an inverse.

As manually:

```
def is_diagonal(matrix):
    #create a dummy matrix
    dummy_matrix = np.ones(matrix.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    # Fill the diagonal of dummy matrix with 0.
    np.fill_diagonal(dummy_matrix, 0)

    return np.count_nonzero(np.multiply(dummy_matrix, matrix)) == 0

diagonal_matrix = np.array([[3, 0, 0],
                            [0, 7, 0],
                            [0, 0, 4]])
print is_diagonal(diagonal_matrix)
>>> True

random_matrix = np.array([[3, 8, 0],
                          [1, 7, 8],
                          [5, 0, 4]])
print is_diagonal(random_matrix)
>>> False
```

scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.diagonal returns the k-th diagonal of the matrix.

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
A = csr_matrix([[1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 5]])
A.diagonal()
array([1, 0, 5])
A.diagonal(k=1)
array([2, 3])
```

Also, ***from scipy.linalg import block_diag*** creates diagonal matrix if input arrays are square, therefore if they are not square, it can not create diagonal matrix.

Please consider in Jupyter you can find out time complexity. ***%timeit yourfunctionname***

Comment: I really don't see how this comment helps. Let's read the question again :)

Comment: @dallonsi scipy.linalg.inv cannot help to check if a matrix is diagonal or not. There are some trick to find by scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.diagonal or from scipy.linalg import block_diag to check it. Any ambiguity? Let me know :)

Comment: Yes, I think that the question was: "Does scipy.linalg.inv checks whether the matrix is diagonal before it applies" some algorithms. The author asks if linalg.inv does that `if diagonal:  inverse manually by taking the diagonal entries d_i and replacing it by 1/d_i else:  apply some complex and more costly algorithm`

Comment: @dallonsi I updated my answer, manually and by methods I mentioned and let's look at their time complexity in Jupyter. If you put scipy.linalg.inv in try expect if it raises LinAlgError when matrix a is singular. Determinant for singular matrix it zero.

Comment: A diagonal matrix does not have to be singular though... @dallonsi got it right.